# Flex DropDownList doesn't select item

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, mxml

I have an implementation for a drop-down list. All the values are there, however it doesn't allow the user to select an item with the mouse instead of just with the arrow keys.

```
    <s:FormItem label="Food:">

        <s:DropDownList id="dropDownList" 
                        dataProvider="{foodList.lastResult.Food_Display_Table.Food_Display_Row}" 
                        labelField="Display_Name" 
                        />
        <s:DropDownList id="TEST">
            <s:dataProvider>
                <mx:ArrayList>
                    <fx:String>Red</fx:String>
                    <fx:String>Orange</fx:String>
                    <fx:String>Yellow</fx:String>
                    <fx:String>Blue</fx:String>
                    <fx:String>Green</fx:String>
                </mx:ArrayList>
            </s:dataProvider>
        </s:DropDownList>
    </s:FormItem>
</s:Form>
```

The first drop-down list is my actual implementation. The second one is a test. I have the same problem with both drop-down lists.

Comment: Is this a mobile project? (This might be a useless question but I'm having two different behaviours on Desktop and Mobile projects)

Answer (score 0):

The DropdownList is not supported in the mobile device profile. There are some opensource implementations that add support for this, and they're quite good : https://www.flextras.com/index.cfm?event=ProductHome&productID=21